# How to show JSON response value in the ckeditor using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, ckeditor

This `response` is coming from the function `master_get_item`

```
{
  "ID": "4",
  "item_title": "slaePrice",
  "item_price": "99999.99",
  "big_pic": "front/images/items/dcba27227bc0f165910a5ba5979a3811.png",
  "item_description": "<p>dsfsdfs</p>",
  "sale_price": "23",
  "status": "enabled"
}
```

I Want to show the value of `item_description` in the `CKEditor` but it can't be showing the value. 
this code I have written in the `success function` of the `Ajax`.

```
modal.find("input#Edititem_description").val(outputData.item_description);
```

**CKeditor code in HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Image" class="control-label">Item Description </label>
    <textarea id="Edititem_description" name="Edititem_description" rows="10" cols="80" style="resize:none"></textarea>
</div>
<!-- /.form-group -->
```

**AjAX Code**

```
    $(".Edit-modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {
       var button = $(e.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
       var ID = button.parents("tr").attr("data-id");
       var modal = $(this);
        $.ajax({
          url: "'.base_url().'Home/master_get_items",
          data: {ID:ID},
          type: "POST",
          success:function(output){
           var outputData = JSON.parse(output);   
          modal.find("input#Edititem_description").val(outputData.item_description);
$("#show_image").attr("src", "'.base_url().'" + outputData.big_pic);
             }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
$("#Edititem_description").val(outputData.item_description)
```

Comment: can you share your complete code snippet or fiddle for more clarifications? Thanks

Comment: I just write a basic code at my end and above script works fine, at least share the function inside of your success callback. Thanks

Comment: Not working out! have you deployed your code on any server? If yes then please share link. Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet looks fine but i cannot verify things until i see the working example. try to upload your on any server.